# select entries of different columns of different tables using dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables

**studentTable**

```
Id | Studentname | Adress
```

**teacherTable**

```
TID | TeacherName | Adress
```

In `studentTable` table I have columns `Id` and in `teacherTable` I have a column `TID`, while using dynamic query how do I select the entries regardless of column name.

```
select ID or PID from @Tablename
```

does not work, how can I do it, any idea?

The query which I tried:

```
SELECT  + '''' +  @TABLE_NAME + '''' + ',' + '''' +  @COLUMN_NAME + '''' + ',' + 'ID  + 
        ' FROM [' + @TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: You haven't explained the context. Why are you attempting to select from different tables using the same query? Why not have two different queries? See [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am using this dynamic query in stored procedure,I need the output of all tables in one table which I got it working  .Every table has ID only TeacherTable has TID..if I write two query any one query will give error,I dont know how to resolve.if you think this problem can be solved using two query please leave the code

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a dynamic query, that would be slow.

Here is how you do it, two queries unioned together.

```
SELECT 'student' as [type], ID as [ID], studentname as name, address
from studentTable
where ID = @inID

union all

SELECT 'teacher' as [type], TID as [ID], teachername as name, address
from teacherTable
where TID = @inID
```

Comment: I need to select ID where @columnname='rasa'

Comment: ex:select ID or TID from @TABLENAME where @COLUMNNAME='rasa'

Comment: I need query either to select ID or TID,when cursor is inside it shoud execute if the column name is ID,or PID

Comment: @user2857662 - stop using cursors.  cursors are not SQL, that way lies madness... learn how SQL works.

Comment: @user2857662 - I changed the query to select both ID and TID.